# Can't connect Kubernetes endpoints IPs with created as an headless service

Tags: ip, kubernetes, endpoint, headless, kube-dns

Created a headless service:

myapp-service-headless.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp-service-headless
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8000
  selector:
    app: myapp
  clusterIP: None
```

After create it to Kubernetes cluster, check its service status:

```
$ kubectl create -f myapp-service-headless.yaml
$ kubectl describe service myapp-service-headless
Name:              myapp-service-headless
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=myapp
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                None
Port:              <unset>  8000/TCP
TargetPort:        8000/TCP
Endpoints:         172.17.0.11:8000,172.17.0.9:8000
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Try to connect `172.17.0.11:8000` or `172.17.0.9:8000`, pending and no result.

Here using `kube-dns`: `myapp-service-headless.default.svc.cluster.local` in the application. Now it's in the container of pods.

So how to connect to these applications from other application via API? Which IP can been used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you expose your container port inside your Endpoint (Pod)?

From what i knew, the headless service can be used to generate entries in kube-dns based on how you configure the Service, as discussed [in this doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#a-records-and-hostname-based-on-pods-hostname-and-subdomain-fields).

However, you can create another Service with `type: NodePort` that selects your backend Pods, and expose them on a [NodePort/LB](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services---service-types).

Comment: No, I didn't expose a container port yet. Since I thought can't expose it in `clusterIP: None` case about service.